# How to determine A/B test design and result

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I am conducting a test for a traveling website.
The control will see a red button with "Free" text, while the variant will see a blue button with "Buy Now" text. 
I am new at statistics and the materials I find are confusing so excuse me for the basic information I require..

1. What kind of test is it? seems like t-test
2. How do I determine the sample sizes up front? This is important.
3. The acceptable significant level is 95%, how do I know if the significant level was reached? and how to calculate the P-value
4. I was told the site owner takes 2.5% error upfront - no matter if alpha or beta - what does that mean?

Again, I am aware some of the sections seem simple but I need the basics to move forward.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the dependent variable?

Comment: Hi Sven, Conversion rate - meaning the number of users who actually clicked the button.